# Assistance with nodejs/express/supertest

Tags: node.js, express, supertest

New to NodeJS and Express3 ... working through the tutorial i found at:

http://www.scotchmedia.com/tutorials/express/authentication

It seems rather helpful but i seem to be having some difficulty with getting a supertest to pass.

This is the test:

```
describe('POST /signup', function () {
  it('should redirect to "/account" if the form is valid', function (done) {
     var post = {
        givenName: 'Barrack',
        familyName: 'Obama',
        email: 'Bob@bob.com',
        password: 'secret'
     };
     request(app)
        .post('/signup')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
       .send(post)
       .expect(302)
       .end(function (err, res) {
         should.not.exist(err);
         // confirm the redirect
         res.header.location.should.include('/account');
         done();
       });
   });
 });
```

The /signup route is handled by:

exports.signup = function (req, res) {

```
console.log("Calling Signup")

 req.onValidationError(function (msg) {
   //Redirect to `/signup` if validation fails
    console.log("Validation Failed: " + msg + "  " + req.param('email'));
    return res.redirect('/signup');
 });

 req.check('password', 'Please enter a password with a length between 4 and 34 digits').len(4, 34);
 req.check('givenName', 'Please enter your first name').len(1);
 req.check('familyName', 'Please enter your last name').len(1);
 req.check('email', 'Please enter a valid email').len(1).isEmail();

 // If the form is valid craete a new user
 var newUser = {
   name: {
     givenName: req.body.givenName,
     familyName: req.body.familyName
   },
   email: req.body.email

 };
```

}

The difficulty is that the validation is always failing.

my app.j contains the following use statements:

```
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

//
//Routes
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.post('/signup', users.signup);
```

Out of ideas ... seems like req.body.xxx is not bound ...

Appreciate any guidance to reduce my level of ignorance.

Cheers

Comment: Take a look at this. I asked a question similar to this and was having issues with the body being undefined. It looks like your problem might be a bit different than mine was, but maybe the example will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594611/node-js-express-mocha-supertest-rest-api-empty-response-body